# perl remove degree symbol

Tags: regex, perl

I open a CSV file using utf8, then read the file into a multidimentional hash.   Evething works.

```
use Text::CSV;
.
.
.
open ($fh, '<:utf8', $input);
.
.
.
```

Unfortunately, some of the columns contain a degree symbol which I need to strip out.  I am already removing other characters using regex expressions, but I can't seem to figure out how to strip out the degree symbol. Example of other regex expressions I am using.

```
$sorted{$pkey}{"desc"} =~ s/\r\n//g; # strip NL from middle of value.
```

How do I strip out the degree symbol, or any non-standard punctuation symbol?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you consider non-standard?

Comment: Could you provide the output of `use Data::Dumper; local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper $sorted{$pkey}{desc};`? This would show us the actual data you are trying to transform.

Comment: @ikegami any character that is not a s US-EN keyboard

Comment: @amom when I add the Dumper statements as above, I get "Maiformed UTF-8 character (fatal) at /usr/lib/perl/5.10/Data/Dumper.pm Line 662, <$fh> line 317."

Comment: Now *this* is interesting. Somewhere you messed up your de- and encoding. At any point in your program, do you add characters to the string from the filehandle? (Substitution or concatenation). Is your script saved as UTF-8? If so, do you have `use utf8`? What would be the output when you remove the `:utf8`-layer from `$fh`?

Comment: using file -bi, the input CSV file is utf-8.  The perl script is us-ascii.  I open and save as using gedit utf-8 and is still is us-ascii.   Not sure if that is OK.  I tried removeing the :utf8 layer with no change.  I also have the use utf8 defined in the perl script.  When i open the input CSV file in an editor the degree symbol is present.   when i less the input source file or the output file to the screen, both have an inverse video <B0> where the degree symbol is.

Comment: i was able to get the Dumper suggestion to work.  The characters where the degree symbol is are:  \x{b0}

Comment: Now the =~ s/\x{b0}//g method works! I guess it had to be lower case. The other methods suggested below using the degree symbol or the charnames didn't remove the degree symbol. Go figure. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think if you use the safer `:encoding(UTF-8)` rather than `:utf8`, you'll find your file isn't encoded using UTF-8.

Comment: I beleive both the source CSV and perl script are UTF-8

Answer (score 4):

If your source code is saved using UTF-8, you should be able to write

```
use utf8;  # Tell Perl the source code is UTF-8
$sorted{$pkey}{"desc"} =~ s/°//g
```

Whether or not you `use utf8`, you should be able to write

```
use charnames ':full';  # Needed before 5.16
$sorted{$pkey}{"desc"} =~ s/\N{DEGREE SIGN}//g
```

Comment: And since strings are made of numbers, you could also look by number: `$sorted{$pkey}{"desc"} =~ s/\x{00B0}//g`. However, that's far less readable than the previously presented solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  #1 doesn't seem to work.  #2 I added use charnames, but still doesn't work.

Comment: @Elvis Never, ever say ["it doesn't work"](http://tlp-perl.blogspot.se/2013/06/its-not-working.html) again, please. Especially not three times in a row. Use your words. Say "it doesn't remove the degree char". Try printing the offending character's number with `print ord($yourcharhere)`.

Comment: @Elvis, `x{B0}` is not a degree sign. It's 5 characters. If you meant `\x{B0}`, then something you said isn't true because `\x{B0}` and `\x{00B0}` are 100% equivalent.

Comment: hum, except maybe because of bugs in ancient versions of Perl?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over the perl version,  but I think it is 5.10.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the issue. It's a UTF-8 file with a degree symbol. Can you not type the degree symbol? Is your computer not using UTF 8? Are you using an older version of Perl that's not Unicode compatible?

The UTF-8 encoding for a degree symbol is `C2` `B0`. You can specify the two hex bytes in a substitution if you so desire. This works on Linux and Macs which run UTF-8 natively. It should work on Windows' default encoding:

```
my $string = "Man, It's hot. It must be 100° out here!";
$string =~ s/\xc2\xb0/ degrees/g;
say $string;  # Prints "Man, It's hot. It must be 100 degrees out here!";
```

Be very, very careful when you munge UTF-8 files like this because you could end up making a character sequence that is invalid.

This works on operating systems that use UTF-8 (which Windows can if you set the correct code page), that you're using a modern version of Perl, and the file is using the actual Unicode symbol:

```
use utf8;  #MUST BE SET!!!!

$string =~ s/\N{U+00B0}/ degrees/;
```

Comment: The first example (with `\xc2\xb0`) will very specifically *not* work if the input is correctly decoded (which it appears to be from the code sample). It will only match U+00C2 followed by U+00B0.

Comment: I had it wrong in my description. The degree symbol is represented in UTF-8 as two hex bytes `c2` and `b0` not `c2` and `b2`. However, the code is correct. The `U+xxxx` format represents the Unicode mapping which is `U+00B0` for the degree sign and not `U00C2` and `U+00B0`. The first bit of code is assuming a computer that is using an eight bit character code page such as Code Page 1252 used in Windows in the U.S. If that is the case, it will work. The second code bit is representing the actual Unicode value, and is preferred if you are using UTF-8 natively like on Mac OS X or Linux.

Comment: The source CSV file comes from a Windows enviroment which I use WinSCP to copy to a Linux machine and ran dos2unix. The source CSV file indicates it is UTF-8 and the perl script was created from scratch on the Linux host. I used GEDIT to perform a save as and selected UTF-8.

Comment: If the file was created on Windows, and you didn't set the codepage, it should be Code Page 1252 which is sometimes (incorrectly) called Latin1. Running `dos2unix` only munges the line endings. There is a `--convmode` on my version, but that doesn't handle wide chars. Run the command `od -ctxc $file | less`. This will let you see exactly how that degree symbol is encoded. If it's two bytes and they're `c2 b0`, it's UTF-8. If it's just one byte and it's just `b0`, it's Code Page 1252. Let me know which one. Also, can you type the degree symbol on your computer?